# Output of numpy.random.choice appears as if it hasn't taken the probability list into account

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list of items,

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

and I'm trying to create another list of `items` such that probability of occurrence of each item is predefined. So I use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

```
from numpy.random import choice
from collections import Counter

total_count = 100000

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
probability = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05]
rand_items = choice(items, total_count, probability)
items_counter = Counter(rand_items)

for item, count in items_counter.most_common():
    print(f"{item}: {100 * count / total_count:.1f}%")
```

Now the output for this code is something like this:

```
(venv) PS D:\Code\python> python .\random\random_selection.py
c: 20.2%
d: 20.1%
e: 19.9%
b: 19.9%
a: 19.8%
```

It's clearly not correct. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
Generate a non-uniform random sample from np.arange(5) of size 3:

np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])
array([3, 3, 0])
```

So I should've replaced this line:

```
rand_items = choice(items, total_count, probability)
```

with this:

```
rand_items = choice(items, total_count, p=probability)
```

and we can see that it works:

```
(venv) PS D:\Code\python> python .\random\random_selection.py
a: 40.0%
b: 30.0%
c: 20.0%
e: 5.1%
d: 4.9%
```